# Using head ala tail -f

Tags: linux, unix

Log files that get extended at the tail can be read live using `tail -f` command

Is there anyway to do the same with a log that gets appended at the beginning?

The man page for `head` doesn't help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TomH is correct, and also, how should head output the changes? However, if all you are looking for is a continually refreshed view of the first n lines, try

```
watch head file.txt
```

or

```
watch -n 1 -d head file.txt
```

Answer (score 7):

Well you can't "append at the beginning" of a file. The only way to achieve that affect would be to rewrite the whole file, but short of doing a text match `head` would have no way of knowing what had happened.

It's easy for `tail` as it just keeps track of the position it read up to and then keeps trying to read more bytes beyond that position.

Comment: Using *sparse* files, it might be possible to prepend to a file.  Still, appending is much the superior approach.

Comment: @TomH, my use case was a little different. It's not a conventional file, but the output of git reflog. I wanted a way to constantly refresh the output, so that I can keep track of what's happening.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.